# Delete PHP Data from MYSQL after display

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, random

After the data is displayed I want the exact text to get deleted from MySQL
I have a random generator that gets data from a row and displays it random

Architecture :
"minecraft" and inside the table its a row named "list"

```
<?php
    // Connect to database server
    mysql_connect("localhost", "bdweb_panel", "password") or die (mysql_error ());
    // Select database
    mysql_select_db("bdweb_panel") or die(mysql_error());
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM minecraft";
// Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
// Array to hold all data
$rows = array();
// Loop the recordset $rs
// Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysql_fetch_array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    // add row to array.
    $rows[] = $row;
}
// Close the database connection
mysql_close();

// Max rand number
$max = count($rows) - 1;

// print out random combination of data.
echo $rows[rand(0, $max)][0] . " " 
?>
```

Update :

To be more explicit

This is the architecture from the DB

[image]

and the php page with a refresh button

[image]

Each time a user is pressing the refresh button he gets a data from the DB (EX : test1, and if he press once again test2 or test3 or test 4 - all random data) all random. Once he gets for example test 1, the text 1 data from the DB deletes so it will not be generated once more again, so after he press the refresh button he will display a data and at the same time he will delete it from the data base.

Comment: And what do you want to delete ?

Comment: After the text is displayed on the page i want it to be deleted from the database so it cant be displayed after that

Answer (score 0):

Since mysql is deprecated you should use mysqli and prepared statements;

Heres a short example how to delete a mysql entry

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM table WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id); 
$stmt->execute();
```

But if you just want to delete the column of an entry you need to use an UPDATE query

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE table SET column = ? WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('si',$new_value, $id); 
$stmt->execute();
```

where $new_value can be null or whatever you want to.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question:

```
<?php
    ...
    $max = count($rows) - 1;
    $r = rand(0, $max);

    /// if $rows[$r][0] is ID column        
    mysql_query("delete from minecraft where id = ".$rows[$r][0]; 

  OR
    mysql_query("update minecraft set list='' where id=".$rows[$r][0]; 
    echo $rows[$r][0];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update :

To be more explicit

This is the arhitecture from the DB https://i.stack.imgur.com/crvh0.png and the php page with a refresh button https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd6Vj.png

Each time a user is pressing the refresh button he gets a data from the DB ( EX : test1 , and if he press once again test2 or test3 or test 4 - all random data ) all random . Once he gets for example test 1 , the text 1 data from the DB deletes so it will not be generated once more again , so after he press the refresh button he will display a data and at the same time he will delete it from the data base.